# Why my SQL syntax is wrong?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have the following SQL query where I want to get results through two variables. However, I'm getting a syntax error, more specifically:

```
near '+'pablo'+ '%' AND apellido LIKE '%' +'rodriguez'+ '%'' at line 1 at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32&
insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId,
Int32&affectedRows, Int32& insertedId) at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32
statementId, Boolean force) at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at
ProyectoProgra4Nota3.modelos.Usuario.buscarQuery(String search, String search2)
```

This is my query:

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
comando.Connection = con.usaConexion();
comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%' +@search+ '%' AND apellido LIKE '%' +@search2+ '%' ";

comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search2", search2);

MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Usuario u2 = new Usuario();

    u2.Correo = reader["correo"].ToString();
    u2.Nombre = reader["nombre"].ToString();
    u2.Apellido = reader["apellido"].ToString();
    u2.Clave = reader["clave"].ToString();

    lista.Add(u2);
}
```

Comment: What if you add the wildcards in your code instead of in the SQL `.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + search + "%")` and `Like @search`?

Comment: @midori Did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, it adds the wild cards directly to the parameter instead of in the query itself. It would really help if you could post an English stack trace / error message.

```
using(MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand())
{
    comando.Connection = con.usaConexion();
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE @search AND apellido LIKE @search2";

    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%"+search+"%");
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search2", "%"+search2+"%");

    using(MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

You should also wrap your instances where the type implements IDisposable in `using` blocks. This ensures the resources are cleaned up even in the event of an exception. This is especially true for the connection object, named `con` in your case.

Comment: @viveknuna, explain your comment, please

Comment: @viveknuna - SQL injection vulnerabilities are mitigated by proper use of parameters. Writing/defining a query in your code and Sql Injection attacks/vulnerability have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not call query like this. You have to make a stored procedure and call that stored procedure from c# code.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE LIKE '%@search%' and AND apellido LIKE '%@search2%'
```

Note: You should use using with your connection and reader object. or you can do closing and disposing connection in `finally` block.

Adding parameter to command can be done in better than you have written.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@someparam"].Value = someParamValue;
```

Here you are telling the datatype of parameter, so runtime errors can be avoided.

Comment: Not the downvoter but... The OP has % on both sides of the search parameters and your query only has them on one side. Also I believe that `'%@search'` would be taken as a literal string and not use the parameter at all.

Comment: it was a typo I have edited my answer, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuarios 
                       WHERE nombre LIKE '%' " +@search+ '%' 
                       AND apellido LIKE '%' +@search2+ '%' ";
```

Comment: That would not even compile.